# What is the fastest way to fill a combobox in C#?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, combobox, sql-server-ce

What is the fastest way to fill ComboBox in C#?

1. With `Add()`
2. Bind the ComboBox to Dataset

Or there is a faster way ?

Thanks.

Comment: i use SqlCe in WinCe working in .sdf file

Comment: Please add those informationen to your question to prevent downvoting.

Comment: And please define whether you mean "fast" in developer terms or data retrieval terms.

Comment: in "fast" i mean data retrieval

Comment: If your combobox has so many items in it that filling it is an issue, then you probably have a design issue.

Comment: Wow, so many downvotes. This may look like a silly question to a professional but lets not be so harsh to somebody who is probably new. Can't hurt to explain the reason for the downvotes and. more importantly, the issue with the question.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably find that the fastest way of doing this will be to read the DB from a datareader, then call .Add() in a loop, but using the DataReader's numerically indexed fields (instead of the named properties).

Comment: We should also note that combining the UI and DB code (while being technically the fastest) is probably not the most elegant means of doing this. Separating out the layers is worth the slight overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using databinding is much less code for anything other than one item:

myComboBox.DataSource = myDataSet;
myComboBox.DataBind();

Of course, this assumes your DataSet already contains data. Perhaps you could refine your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your fastest way will probably be either binding to a [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx) or iterating over a DataReader and using the `Add()` method of the ComboBox. Either way, the key isn't whether you're binding or iterating (I haven't instrumented those and therefore can't tell you which is faster), the key is using the DataReader.

By using a DataSet, you're loading and populating a fairly heavy data object. If you're noticing speed issues, this is probably the culprit. Just switching to DataReader (whether using `Add()` or binding) will probably get you a boost.

Of course, all this is assuming you're seeing a speed issue in the first place. If you're not, and no one's complaining about the speed of your app, and your app doesn't have a projected growth that would cause an issue, then *stay on your current path!* ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)